# template member function inheritance

Tags: c++, function, templates, member

I have a non-template class with a template member function similar to below.

```
class Component
{
public:
static const int HASH_ID = 0;
virtual int HashID() const {return Component::HASH_ID;}
virtual bool is(int hash_id) const {return Component::HASH_ID == hash_id;}
template<typename T> bool is() const {return this->is(T::HASH_ID);}
};

class Transform : public Component
{
 public:
 static const int HASH_ID = 1;
 virtual int HashID() const {return Transform::HASH_ID;}
 virtual bool is(int hash_id) const {return Transform::HASH_ID == hash_id;}
};
```

My issue is that the Transform class won't let me call the template function.

Here is the test code I wrote that won't compile

```
int main(void)
{
  Transform test_component;
  Transform* transform = &test_component;
  Component* component = &test_component;

  std::cout << component->is<Transform>() << std::endl; //No issues

  //Won't compile unless I comment out this line
  std::cout << transform->is<Transform>() << std::endl; //Says I am missing argument list

  std::cout << transform->is(Transform::HASH_ID) << std::endl; //Works Fine!
  return 0;
}
```

Any ideas why this doesn't work?

Comment: Add this line to `Transform`: `using Component::is;`. The way name lookup works, `Transform::is` hides all entities named `is` from the base class, whether with matching signature or otherwise. The `using` declaration then brings the names from base class scope into `Transform`'s scope, so they are no longer being hidden. Long term, it would probably be best to give two functions different names, or else you'd keep hitting this problem.

Comment: Perfect! I'll do some more testing, if it needs a new name I'll change it. Makes sense.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik If he gives it different names, wouldn't that prevent derived classes from being used polymorphically?

Comment: I don't believe he means each one needs a new name. I think he means use another name besides "is". The issue is that overloading the virtual version of the function "is" causes all base class functions called "is" to be hidden. If it had any other name besides "is" in the base class it would not become hidden when derived from. So I could simply call it "isTemplate" and it would work for all derived classes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
virtual bool is(int hash_id) const {return Transform::HASH_ID == hash_id;}
```

is hiding

```
template<typename T> bool is() const {return this->is(T::HASH_ID);}
```

If a derived class declares a method with the same name as a method defined by the base class, the derived class' method hides the base class' one.

Comment: Yeah Igor gave the proper solution above. Never had an issue with that kind of name mangling before when deriving from a class. Need to use "using Component::is;" and then it will unhide it.